# Jython- using variables in function calls syntax

Tags: python, websphere, jython

I am working with Jython to automate deployments in WebSphere. I am wrapping my py script with a shell script to pass needed variables for WAS's built-in functions.

The stock call with hardcoded values looks like this:

```
appManager=AdminControl.queryNames('cell=wsapp2Node01Cell,node=TARGETNODE,type=
                                       ApplicationManager,process=server1,*')
AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'stopApplication', 'ApplicationName')
```

I want to replace ApplicationName with my variable and still retain quotes but can't figure out the syntax.

```
MyAppVariable= sys.argv[3]
appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('cell=wsapp2Node01Cell,node=TARGETNODE,type=
                                         ApplicationManager,process=server1,*')
AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'stopApplication', 'MyAppVariable')
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Wait, wat? If you put it in quotes, it's a string literal. If you don't, it refers to a variable. If you want to refer to a variable, leave out the quotes. Say, why do you want to "retain quotes"?

Comment: I agree with delnan. And the answer would be: `AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'stopApplication', sys.argv[3])`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is as simple as the following:

```
AdminControl.invoke(appManager, 'stopApplication', MyAppVariable)
```

Does that work? If not, what does it do?